# Pyspark PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm running a spark job in Databricks and keep receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 844, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 980, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1038, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The job which runs it sometimes fails with this, and other times succeeds, it also started popping up all of a sudden about 2 weeks after no major changes were made that could lead to this. This seems very random.

Is there a way to further debug what may be causing this?

Comment: Check t see if the acessed cluster, is already open somewhere else

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 i dont think it is, each job runs in a dedicated cluster that spins up just for that job.